# How to create a map with a function pointer as a value, and insert into that map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, function-pointers

My goal: I want to create a map with a string as the key and a function pointer as the value. I then want to insert some key value pairs into the map.

Here's what I have so far. In my header file I have this snippet:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<std::string()>> cMap;
```

In my cpp file is:

```
void Manager::initialize() {
    commandMap["GO"] = &Manager::testfunc;
}
void Manager::testfunc(std::string testvalue) {};
```

I want the &Manager::testfunc to be added to the map and point to the function in my class, but I don't understand any of this very well, and it's not working.

I'm getting the error "Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'". What does that mean?

The 'duplicate' topic uses std::bind, but I believe that's not what I need. How do I add to the value without that? Please, I really don't think the linked topic is for the same problem. I really would appreciate if someone could help me, I've been trying and searching and googling all day and I just can't figure it out by myself.

Comment: Use std::function instead and consider lambdas or std::bind

Comment: A member function pointer has a different type than a pointer to a free function.